# How to save a plot as image on disk from Viewer in RStudio?

Tags: r, highcharts, reporters

Summary: my ultimate goal is to use `rCharts`, and specifically `Highcharts`, as part of a `ReporteRs` PowerPoint report automation workflow. One of the charts I would like to use is rendered as html in the Viewer pane in Rstudio, and `addPlot(function() print(myChart))` does not add it to the PowerPoint. As a workaround, I decided to try to save `myChart` to disk, from where I could just add it to the PowerPoint that way.

So my question is really, **How do I get my html image into my `ReporteRs` workflow?** Either getting it saved to a disk, or getting it to be readable by `ReporteRs` would solve my problem.

This question is really the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk), but I'm using `rCharts`, specifically the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486186/modify-existing-function-for-a-radar-plot-in-r):

```
#if the packages are not already installed
install.packages('devtools')
require(devtools)
install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')

#code creates a radar chart using Highcharts
library(rCharts)
#create dummy dataframe with number ranging from 0 to 1
df<-data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d","e"),val1=runif(5,0,1),val2=runif(5,0,1))
#muliply number by 100 to get percentage
df[,-1]<-df[,-1]*100

myChart <- Highcharts$new()
myChart$chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line",height=500)
myChart$xAxis(categories=df$id, tickmarkPlacement= 'on', lineWidth= 0)
myChart$yAxis(gridLineInterpolation= 'circle', lineWidth= 0, min= 0,max=100,endOnTick=T,tickInterval=10)
myChart$series(data = df[,"val1"],name = "Series 1", pointPlacement="on")
myChart$series(data = df[,"val2"],name = "Series 2", pointPlacement="on")
myChart
```

So if I try

```
> png(filename="~/Documents/name.png")
> plot(myChart)
Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
> dev.off()
```

I get that error.

I've looked into [Highcharts documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview), as well as [many](https://github.com/hafen/trelliscope/blob/master/R/thumb.R) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802528/how-to-save-an-image-of-the-chart-on-the-server-with-highcharts) [potential](https://gist.github.com/philfreo/0a4d899de4257e08a000) [solutions](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2014/03/save-highchart-as-binary-image.html) that seem to rely on Javascript and `phantomjs`. If your answer relies on `phantomjs`, please assume I have no idea how to use it. `webshot` is another package I found which is even so kind as to include an `install_phantomjs()` function, but from what I could find, it requires you to turn your output into a `Shiny` object first.

My question is really a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065049/save-rstudio-viewer-to-image), which is **not** a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094507/how-to-save-interactive-charts-from-dygraph) because that is how to embed the html output in Rmarkdown, not save it as a file on the hard drive.

I also found [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548167/render-rcharts-using-reporters-package-in-powerpoint) which is also basically the same.

edit: as noted by @hrbrmstr and scores of others, radar charts are not always the best visualization tools. I find myself required to make one for this report.

Comment: Use the `webshot` package. there are examples of how to do that on SO but it's pretty straightforward: `myChart$save("/tmp/rcharts.html") ; webshot::webshot("/tmp/rcharts.html", file="/tmp/out.png", delay=2)`. But, why not just use the `radarchart` package?

Comment: `webshot` uses `phantomjs`. I didn't see any `radarchart` output that looked any good. I did just see that a bug I had with `ggradar` was addressed so I may go back and try that package.

Comment: Yes, it uses phantomjs and it _actually has_ an `install_phantomjs()`  function (need to read help pages). As far as radar charts go (they're usually terrible visualization choices) `fsmb::radarchart()` [doesn't do a bad job](https://www.dropbox.com/s/agmc0peh2xywky9/Picture1.png?dl=1) and  I find it infinitely better (more visually appealing) than rCharts (i.e. the ones this post generates) but there are way better vis choices IMO.

Comment: edited to clarify that I tried `webshot` and `install_phantomjs()` previously but it didn't appear to be what I was looking for as I went through that and many other readme files on github. Thank you for your suggestion that I read the help pages. If you post the code in the first comment, I will accept it - I was looking all over for something like `myChart$save(filepath)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer turned out to be in the `webshot` package. @hrbrmstr provided the following code, which would be run at the end of the code I posted in the question:

```
# If necessary
install.packages("webshot")
library(webshot)
install_phantomjs()

# Main code
myChart$save("/tmp/rcharts.html")
webshot::webshot("/tmp/rcharts.html", file="/tmp/out.png", delay=2)
```

This saves the plot to the folder as an `html`, and then takes a picture of it, which is saved as a `png`.

I can then run the `ReporteRs` workflow by using `addImage(mydoc, "/tmp/out.png")`.