# Save viewer object rendered in RStudio as image

Tags: r, rstudio

I created an object that is viewed in the RStudio viewer, such as chart in `plotly` or `highcharter` or a map in `leaflet`. I would like to save that object as a png. There are a number of ways to do this. For example, there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160125/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-disk-from-viewer-in-rstudio) method that uses `webshot`. It's possible to use `orca`. There are several methods. The problem with all of these is that the output image is slightly different than the version seen in the viewer. This is a problem for me because I need both the interactive version of the chart as well as a static version and I don't want to have to create two versions and write all the code associated with producing both to make sure each one comes out just as I need.

However, RStudio has a built-in method that can be accessed by clicking "Export -> Save as Image" in the viewer pane. I would like to use this method because it preserves the layout exactly as seen in the viewer.

I tried using `R`'s built-in plot saving method of `png`, `plot` and `devoff`, but that appears to only work for plot objects, not viewer objects.

There has to be a way to reproduce the physical steps of saving as an image in RStudio programmatically, right? Doing it manually would be really time-consuming.

Here's an sample chart in `plotly` that shows up in the viewer.

```
plot_ly(z = ~volcano, type = "surface")
```